# How to use pthread library in DevC++?

Tags: windows-vista, pthreads

I downloaded pthread package from [pthread](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/). What should I do now to use it in DevC++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Download pthreads devpak [Download](https://code.google.com/archive/p/oopthread/downloads)
2. Install it in Dev C++
3. Create new Project in Dev C++
4. After that go to Project menu -> Project Option -> In that select "Parameter Tab"
5. Select "add Library or object" option
6. Select "libpthreadGC2.a" file from installation directory of Dev c++ 
   It will be in LIB directory.
7. Press ok
8. Now test following sample code ready for running..

Sample Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;
void * fun_thread1(void *data)
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    { 
        cout<<endl<<"In Thread 1"<<endl;
    }     
}
void * fun_thread2(void *data)
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    { 
        cout<<endl<<"In Thread 2"<<endl;
    }     
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status;
    // creating thread objects
    pthread_t thrd_1;
    pthread_t thrd_2;
    // create thread
    pthread_create(&thrd_1,NULL,fun_thread1,(void *)0);
    pthread_create(&thrd_2,NULL,fun_thread2,(void *)0);    
    pthread_join(thrd_1, (void **)&status);
    pthread_join(thrd_2, (void **)&status);
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The link to the devpak results in a 404.